# what's causing video playback of video written with opencv very fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyautogui

i am trying to make a screen recorder using opencv and pyautogui in python for a specific window and when i save the video then try to play it the playback turned out to be very fast than usual how to fix it?

```
import os
import cv2
import pygetwindow
import pyautogui
import platform
import numpy as np
import time

# Get the desired window
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('seafight')[0]
    window.activate()
    left, top = window.left, window.top
    right, bottom = window.right, window.bottom

    # Ensure the captured region matches the desired area
    # You can adjust these values to capture a larger or smaller region
    left_offset = 0
    top_offset = 0
    right_offset = 0
    bottom_offset = 0
    left += left_offset
    top += top_offset
    right -= right_offset
    bottom -= bottom_offset

# Specify the filename for the video
filename = 'result3.avi'

# Construct the full path to the video file in the current directory
video_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)

# Set the frame rate (e.g., 20 frames per second)
frame_rate = 20

# Create a video writer object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_path, fourcc, frame_rate, (right - left, bottom - top))

# Initialize variables for frame count and timer
frame_count = 0
start_time = time.time()

# Main loop to capture frames
while True:
    # Capture the content of the window even when it's not in focus
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(left, top, right - left, bottom - top))
    frame = np.array(screenshot)
    
    # Convert the frame to BGR format (OpenCV format)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    
    # Write the frame to the video file
    out.write(frame)
    
    # Increment the frame count
    frame_count += 1
    
    # Calculate elapsed time
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    
    # Calculate the desired time for the next frame
    next_frame_time = frame_count / frame_rate
    
    # Calculate the sleep time to achieve the desired frame rate
    sleep_time = next_frame_time - elapsed_time
    
    if sleep_time > 0:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
    
    # Display the captured frame
    cv2.imshow('Captured Frame', frame)
    
    # Reset frame count and timer if a second has passed
    if elapsed_time >= 1.0:
        frame_count = 0
        start_time = time.time()
    
    # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video writer and close the OpenCV window
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Print the frame rate
print(f'Frame rate: {frame_rate} FPS')
```

i tried the code above and i am expecting the playback to be normal but it is faster than that